# Delete list of elements from a list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have two lists `listBig` and `listSmall` and I want to delete all elements of `listSmall` from `listBig`. Assume that all elements of `listSmall` are present in `listBig` and that if there are multiple instances of an element of `listSmall` in `listBig`, they *must not* be deleted, meaning deleting one is the key.

Is there a better way to achieve this than:

```
listBig = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,7]
listSmall = [4,7]
deleted = 0
inner = 0
for outer in range(0,len(listSmall)):
    while not deleted == len(listSmall):
        if listSmall[outer]==listBig[inner]:
            listBig.remove(listBig[inner])
            inner=0
            deleted+=1
            break
        inner+=1
print listBig

OUTPUT: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 4, 7]
```

Comment: modified the lists to show that if there are elements in listSmall which occir more than once in listBig, multiple occurrences MUST NOT BE DELETED. Thanks. Sorry for creating some confusion.

Comment: Do you have ordering constraint? Why do you remove one of the duplicated element in listBig?@user1989682

Comment: No. There are no ordering constraints.

Comment: The big list was created by adding elements from multiple small lists. I want to "undo" the effect of one of the small lists. The duplicates were added by other small lists. So they must stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the duplicates, list.remove(x) only removes the first element it finds in the list.

```
    listBig = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,7]
    listSmall = [4,7]
    for item in listSmall: listBig.remove(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
listBig = [item for item in listBig if item not in listSmall]
```

Comment: if any list has duplicated elements, `set(list_nname)` would only keep one left

Answer (score 1):

I would convert your `listSmall` to a `set` (for faster membership lookup), then you can use a simple list comprehension

```
>>> setSmall = set(listSmall)
>>> listBig = [i for i in listBig if i not in setSmall]
>>> listBig
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
```

Comment: if you change listSmall to set() might be better if listSmall is a long list and there is no duplicated element in listSmall. Because `in` works for set() in constant time, while it does linear time in list @Cyber @user1989682

Comment: @ChesterL I'm not sure I understand your point. As you said the `in` operation is faster for `set` than for `list`. For any decent sized `listSmall`, it would be beneficial to make a `set`.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry for creating some confusion. I realised that in my case, if there are multiple occurrences of an element of listSmall in listBig, they MUST NOT BE deleted. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Cyber As long as there is no repeated element in listSmall, otherwise, set() will keep only one left

Comment: Please check the modified question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to compare every element in both lists and check whether there are any repeated elements. If so, the repeated element will be deleted from listBig

`>>>'listBig[:] = [element for element in listBig if element not in listSmall]`
`>>>print listBig`

`[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]`